# Rendering validation messages RichFaces

Tags: jsf, richfaces, validation, mojarra

I have a form where I have a `rich:select` whether they choose option A or option B an `h:inputText` is rendered.
Initially the `h:inputText` corresponding to option A is rendered and if I leave it blank the `requiredMessage` appears and everything is OK.
Now when I select the second option of the `rich:select` the `h:inputText` for option B is rendered but if I leave it blank the `requiredMessage` doesn't appear.

What am I missing?

My xhtml code is as follows:

```
                <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                    <h:outputLabel for="tipoPersona">Tipo de persona</h:outputLabel>
                    <rich:select id="tipoPersona"
                                 required="true" value="#{userInformationController.tipoPersona}"
                                 requiredMessage="Seleccione el tipo de persona"
                                 defaultLabel="Seleccione una opción">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{userInformationController.tipoPersonaOpciones}"/>
                        <f:ajax event="blur" render="tipoPersonaMessage"/>
                        <f:ajax event="selectitem"
                                render="outputLabelCURP inputTextCURP messageCURP outputLabelRFC inputTextRFC messageRFC"
                                listener="#{userInformationController.doRenderCURP}"/>
                    </rich:select>
                    <rich:message id="tipoPersonaMessage" ajaxRendered="true"
                                  for="tipoPersona"/>


                    <a4j:outputPanel id="outputLabelCURP">
                        <h:outputLabel for="CURP" value="CURP"
                                       rendered="#{userInformationController.curpRendered}"/>
                    </a4j:outputPanel>                        
                    <a4j:outputPanel id="inputTextCURP">
                        <h:inputText id="CURP" required="true"
                                     requiredMessage="Introduzca el CURP"
                                     rendered="#{userInformationController.curpRendered}">
                            <f:ajax event="blur" render="curpMessage"/>
                        </h:inputText>
                    </a4j:outputPanel>
                    <a4j:outputPanel id="messageCURP">
                        <rich:message id="curpMessage" ajaxRendered="true"
                                      for="CURP"
                                      rendered="#{userInformationController.curpRendered}"/>
                    </a4j:outputPanel>


                    <a4j:outputPanel id="outputLabelRFC">
                        <h:outputLabel for="RFC" value="RFC"
                                       rendered="#{not userInformationController.curpRendered}"/>
                    </a4j:outputPanel>
                    <a4j:outputPanel id="inputTextRFC">
                        <h:inputText id="RFC" required="true"
                                     requiredMessage="Introduzca el RFC"
                                     rendered="#{not userInformationController.curpRendered}">
                            <f:ajax event="blur" render="rfcMessage"/>
                        </h:inputText>
                    </a4j:outputPanel>
                    <a4j:outputPanel id="messageRFC">
                        <rich:message id="rfcMessage" ajaxRendered="true"
                                      for="RFC"
                                      rendered="#{not userInformationController.curpRendered}"/>
                    </a4j:outputPanel>
                </h:panelGrid>
```

**UPDATE**

I have made some changes on the UI and now I have this

```
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Datos SURI</legend>
                <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                    <h:outputLabel for="tipoPersona">Tipo de persona</h:outputLabel>
                    <rich:select id="tipoPersona"
                                 required="true" value="#{userInformationController.tipoPersona}"
                                 requiredMessage="Seleccione el tipo de persona"
                                 defaultLabel="Seleccione una opción">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{userInformationController.tipoPersonaOpciones}"/>
                        <f:ajax event="blur" render="tipoPersonaMessage"/>
                        <f:ajax event="selectitem"
                                render="outputLabelCURP inputTextCURP messageCURP 
                                        outputLabelRFC inputTextRFC messageRFC
                                        datosPersonaFisica datosPersonaMoral"
                                listener="#{userInformationController.doRenderTipoPersona}"/>
                    </rich:select>
                    <rich:message id="tipoPersonaMessage" ajaxRendered="true"
                                  for="tipoPersona"/>


                    <a4j:outputPanel id="outputLabelCURP">
                        <h:outputLabel for="CURP" value="CURP"
                                       rendered="#{userInformationController.personaFisicaRendered}"/>
                    </a4j:outputPanel>                        
                    <a4j:outputPanel id="inputTextCURP">
                        <h:inputText id="CURP" required="true"
                                     requiredMessage="Introduzca el CURP"
                                     value="#{userInformationController.curp}"
                                     rendered="#{userInformationController.personaFisicaRendered}">
                            <f:ajax event="blur" render="curpMessage identificadorSURI"
                                    listener="#{userInformationController.doSearchIdSURI}"/>
                        </h:inputText>
                    </a4j:outputPanel>
                    <a4j:outputPanel id="messageCURP">
                        <rich:message id="curpMessage" ajaxRendered="true" for="CURP"
                                      rendered="#{userInformationController.personaFisicaRendered}"/>
                    </a4j:outputPanel>


                    <a4j:outputPanel id="outputLabelRFC">
                        <h:outputLabel for="RFC" value="RFC"
                                       rendered="#{userInformationController.personaMoralRendered}"/>
                    </a4j:outputPanel>
                    <a4j:outputPanel id="inputTextRFC">
                        <h:inputText id="RFC" required="true"
                                     requiredMessage="Introduzca el RFC"
                                     value="#{userInformationController.rfc}"
                                     rendered="#{userInformationController.personaMoralRendered}">
                            <f:ajax event="blur" render="rfcMessage identificadorSURI"
                                    listener="#{userInformationController.doSearchIdSURI}"/>
                        </h:inputText>
                    </a4j:outputPanel>
                    <a4j:outputPanel id="messageRFC">
                        <rich:message id="rfcMessage" ajaxRendered="true" for="RFC"
                                      rendered="#{userInformationController.personaMoralRendered}"/>
                    </a4j:outputPanel>

                    <h:outputLabel for="identificadorSURI">Identificador SURI</h:outputLabel>
                    <h:inputText id="identificadorSURI" disabled="true"
                                 value="#{userInformationController.identificadorSuri}"/>

                </h:panelGrid>
            </fieldset>
```

However, I found that putting my Bean in **RequestScope** isn't firing the listener on both of the `h:inputText` (id='CURP' and id='RFC'), whereas if I put the bean in **ViewScope** the listener is getting fired and processed correctly.

What I need is to actually have the Bean in RequestScope because I need to create a whole new form whether the user changes the value of the `rich:select`. If I keep the scope in ViewScope all the data is kept within the Bean and I will then have to erase the fields when the user changes the value of the select.

Can someone explain to me why is this happening? I could'n figure out what's the trick !

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A request scoped bean is recreated on every single request, also on every single ajax request. So when you change a property by ajax to a new value other than default (e.g. the one responsible for `rendered` attribute), then this change won't be retained in the subsequent requests. So the `rendered` attribute effectively evaluates to `false` and the component and all its children won't be processed anymore during the submit.

The view scope is intended to solve exactly this problem. The bean will live as long as you're interacting with the same view by ajax requests, until you navigate away to a different view or recreate the view. As to the functional requirement of recreating the form on change of `<rich:select>`, just do that inside the `doRenderTipoPersona()` method.

If you really need to stick to the request scope, then you'd need to retain the bean's properties manually based on the request parameter map inside the (post)constructor.

Comment: Thanks. That's was what I imagined (ajax creates new requests). What I did was to kept my bean in View Scope and clear all bean's fields on `<rich:select>` listener.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using to event function you can use the single ajax function

```
<rich:select id="tipoPersona"
                                 required="true" value="#{userInformationController.tipoPersona}"
                                 requiredMessage="Seleccione el tipo de persona"
                                 defaultLabel="Seleccione una opción">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{userInformationController.tipoPersonaOpciones}"/>
                       <f:ajax event="valueChange"
                                render="tipoPersonaMessage outputLabelCURP inputTextCURP messageCURP outputLabelRFC inputTextRFC messageRFC"
                                listener="#{userInformationController.doRenderCURP}"/>
                    </rich:select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe I explain myself wrong, but the problem is not in the **rich:select** the problem is in the **h:inputText** (id='CURP' and id='RFC'). When the `blur` event is fired I want the listener to get called but It doesn't.

Comment: ahan..i have another solution for this you can call a onBlur function on Inputtext where you can have a4j:jsFunction call which call your listener function on the bean.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a solution.

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="onBlurRFC" execute="RFC" render = "rfcMessage identificadorSURI" 
    action="#{userInformationController.doSearchIdSURI}" />     

    <h:inputText id="RFC" required="true"
                                             requiredMessage="Introduzca el RFC"
                                             value="#{userInformationController.rfc}"
                                             rendered="#{userInformationController.personaMoralRendered}" onblur="onBlurRFC()">
                                </h:inputText>
```

Comment: sorry, a4j:jsFunction was missing. a4j:jsFunction will fire a listener on a bean and render the panel. same will be done for CURP input Text.